# Positioning and changing button appearance

Tags: html, button, bootstrap-modal

I'm lost. I have no idea what I'm doing, so please forgive me if I write something stupid or don't understand your answers.

My goal is to have a modal box showing after clicking a button. That's the easy part and I accomplished that already, so yay me.

Basically, I'm using this code:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal2

Now, what I don't know how to do:

1) How do I change the appearance of the button? Can I change it to an image? 
The only thing I could do is place an image IN the button (looks weird), but not replacing it.

2) How do I change the position of the button?
I would like to have few buttons on the left side of the screen (not website but screen). So I would need to adjust them to be on the left side, and I would also need to change the height of all the buttons.

Now, I changed the appearance and the position of the button when trying something else (a slideout), so I know it's possible. But the codes are different and I don't know how to "merge" them. The lines that work in the first one don't work in the another.

And I have absolutely no idea in what language it is. I know that it uses this createElement thing to create this button, but I don't know how to change anything about it. I went through the whole w3school and many topics on this site but I don't know how to use this knowledge - so maybe you could help me out. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an image to open the modal, you should not use the button tag. Just attach your event to an img.

using the example code, replace:

```
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>
```

with

```
<img id="myImg"></img>
```

and attch the click event to "myImg"

```
var img = document.getElementById("myImg");
img.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}
```

Repositioning is going to be a little more difficult to answer without seeing your full code. W3Schools has a good intro to CSS for beginners so I would start there.

Comment: Stupid question, I know, but where and what is my full code? Because I'm using literally the easiest website builder possible - Weebly - no codes if you are not me and don't have extra needs, just drag & drop. So I just put the first half of the code in the header code on the site and the other half in the html drag&drop element and that's it. So I don't know what would be my full code?

Comment: By "full code" here I just meant whatever HTML, CSS, JS, etc. you were using to create your page. Since your using Weebly, that's actually not a stupid question. I know of Weebly but have never used it so I'm not sure how all of your code would be accessed.

Comment: Unfortunately, I changed the button to the image but it's not reacting to the click. No idea what went wrong since I followed your instructions and checked if there are any "btn's" that need to be changed to "img's". But, I was wondering, can't I just somehow address this button's position and appearance like it's done in the <style> part with the appearance of the modal (background, content etc.)? At least there are words I understand ;)

Comment: I hope I won't get banned but this is my website: http://szkoleniepsowtorun.weebly.com/ (an old one anyway and in Polish). As you can see, the modal is working perfectly (it's getting behind the header but I don't care since I can just remove it, the modal works and that's what matters). On the left you have the slideout element I wanted to use but it's not an option because it takes too much space and the buttons couldn't be placed one under another. And the slideout code is from here - maybe that will get you a better view: https://www.webnots.com/css-floating-slideout-widget-for-weebly/

Answer (score 0):

Replace button to code similar to this   id="myBtn" is important

```
 <img id="myBtn" src="image url">
```

And check

https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp

Css is used to design the html elements 
it have some property like

height, background-image , position , float , flex etc

which can help you to achieve your goals.